# Exclude Generated Objects - SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-12c

I am a software developer that supports and develops an application that connects to both Oracle databases and SQL Server databases.

I have created a connection to a database (orcl) using the SYS account.  There are hundreds of system generated tables e.g. access$, aclmv$ etc.  How do I hide all these tables so that I can see the tables I have created.  I have tried applying a filter to the tables (Exclude Generated Objects), but this has not worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing. Unfortunately you can not create fully customized filters, you can use only the predefined ones. Even if you could, there is no reliable way of filtering built-in objects. Starting with 12c, there is a new column in the `USER|ALL|DBA_OBJECTS` views, called `ORACLE_MAINTAINED`, but we can not rely on that, because its is not accurate (for example, AWR objects or some built-in directories and queues are not accounted as maintained by Oracle).

As it was already mentioned, do not use `SYS`, that is for administrative tasks. Create your own user, and log in as that user.